# IE7 align vertically "inline" elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I've a problem with IE7.. I added padding to my inputs (top and bottom). In Firefox and others, the label shows in the middle, but in IE7, it shows at the bottom.. and in IE8, at the top.

I tried to set label `vertical-align:middle` style, but it doesn't work.

Its fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w2wTA/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a height for the 'field' div, and setting the `line-height` attribute equal to that:

```
#field {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

**edit**

You could also try adding a class to both the label and the input, setting the padding:

```
<div id="field">
    <label for="t" class="t">Input:</label> <input type="text" id="t" class="t">
</div>
```

css: (somehow, inline-block is not working, so block with a float will do the trick, though I find this a bit of a 'dirty hack')

```
.t{
    padding: 10px 0;
}

label{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

This seems to work. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNZFN/)

Comment: If you have IE9 you can test 7 and 8 aswell F12 and then just change both docmode and browser mode to the browser you wanna test

Comment: Thanks. First solution doesn't work. But second one does, if I set `display: inline-block` for label.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to add that to my answer. Great!

Comment: you said inline-block is not working.. but it does.. http://jsfiddle.net/w2wTA/18/

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html - inline-block aint fully supported in IE 6 & 7

Comment: Interesting, so my fiddle would perhaps be the better option..?